# io read/write on closed pipe when copying large data

Tags: go, io

I have a video conversion method, I get an array of bytes as output, then I want to pass this array of bytes to a method that would make a preview of the video, but I ran into a problem, namely **io read/write on closed pipe**.

This problem occurs only when converting large files (10MB, 15MB). And not always, on the third iteration of the same file or on the 5th iteration, i.e. the error is not constant for some reason. The most interesting thing is that I can skip the error, and after executing `ThumbnailWithReader` I can successfully create a file without errors, open it, and process it just as smoothly. My first question is, can I ignore this error or not?

```golang
func (f *FFmpeg) ThumbnailWithReader(fileBytes io.Reader, duration string) (bytes []byte, err error) {
    if fileBytes == nil {
        return nil, ErrInvalidArgument
    }

    command := "ffmpeg"
    args := []string{
        "-loglevel", "fatal",
        "-y",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-ss", duration,
        "-vframes", "1",
        "-vcodec", "mjpeg",
        "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+faststart",
        "-hls_list_size", "0",
        "-f", "image2",
        "pipe:1",
    }

    return f.executeCommand(command, args, fileBytes)
}
```

You may notice my attempts to somehow solve this problem, but unfortunately it didn't go away

```golang
func (f *FFmpeg) executeCommand(command string, args []string, fileBytes io.Reader) (bytes []byte, err error) {
    if fileBytes == nil {
        return nil, ErrInvalidArgument
    }

    // Create a CmdRunner instance for executing the FFmpeg command.
    composer := &CmdRunner{}
    composer.Command = command
    composer.Args = args

    // Initialize input and output pipes.
    writer := composer.InitStdInPipe()
    reader := composer.InitStdOutPipe()

    // Use WaitGroup to synchronize goroutines.
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    // Goroutine for reading data from the output pipe.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer reader.Close()
        defer wg.Done()

        // Read data from the output pipe.
        data, errR := io.ReadAll(reader)
        // Safely update the 'bytes' variable.
        f.mutex.Lock()
        bytes = data
        err = errR
        f.mutex.Unlock()
    }()

    // Goroutine for writing data to the input pipe.
    wg.Add(1)
    //go func() {
    //  defer writer.Close()
    //  defer wg.Done()
    //
    //  // Copy data from the input to the output pipe.
    //  _, errc := io.Copy(writer, fileBytes)
    //  if errc != nil {
    //      if errors.Is(io.ErrClosedPipe, errc) {
    //          fmt.Print("close pipe\n")
    //      }
    //  }
    //}()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        // Create a buffer to store the data read from fileBytes.
        buf := make([]byte, 8192) // or any appropriate buffer size

        for {
            // Read data from fileBytes into the buffer.
            n, errr := fileBytes.Read(buf)
            if errr != nil {
                if errr == io.EOF {
                    // End of file reached, close the writer.
                    _ = writer.Close()
                    return
                } else {
                    // Other error occurred, report it.
                    fmt.Println("Error reading from fileBytes:", errr)
                    return
                }
            }

            // Write the data from the buffer to the writer.
            _, errr = writer.Write(buf[:n])
            if errr != nil {
                // Error occurred while writing, report it.
                fmt.Println("Error writing to writer:", errr)
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    // Run the FFmpeg command with pipes and wait for completion.
    err = <-composer.RunWithPipe()
    wg.Wait()

    return bytes, err
}
```

```golang
func (c *CmdRunner) RunWithPipe() <-chan error {
    // Create a buffered error channel to communicate errors asynchronously.
    errCh := make(chan error, 1)

    // Prepare the command to be executed, adding some common parameters like disabling stats and setting log level to 0.
    command := c.Args

    // Create a new exec.Cmd instance with the specified command and arguments.
    cmd := exec.Command(c.Command, command...)

    // Create buffers to capture the standard output and error streams of the command.
    var outb, errb bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &outb
    cmd.Stderr = &errb

    // If an input pipe has been set, connect it to the standard input of the command.
    if c.stdInPipeReader != nil {
        cmd.Stdin = c.stdInPipeReader
    }

    // If an output pipe has been set, connect it to the standard output of the command.
    if c.stdOutPipeWriter != nil {
        cmd.Stdout = c.stdOutPipeWriter
    }

    // Start the execution of the command asynchronously.
    err := cmd.Start()

    // Start a goroutine to handle the execution and error handling.
    go func() {
        // Check if there was an error starting the command.
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("failed at startup execution of command, command: %v, error: %v", command, err)
            close(errCh)
            return
        } else {
            //defer c.closePipes()
            // Wait for the command to finish its execution.
            err = cmd.Wait()
            // Check if there was an error during the execution.
            if err != nil {
                err = fmt.Errorf("failed finish command execution, command: %v, error: %v", command, err)
            }
            // Close pipes to avoid resource leaks.
            go c.closePipes()

            // Send the final error status to the error channel.
            errCh <- err
        }

        // If there is any content in the standard error buffer, send it as an additional error message.
        if errb.String() != "" {
            errCh <- fmt.Errorf("stderr, error: %v", err)
        }
        close(errCh)
    }()

    // Return the error channel to the caller for asynchronous error handling.
    return errCh
}
```

My second question is how can I fix the error **io: read/write on closed pipe**? I am trying to keep the service logic using pipe for the sake of saving on reads, I can avoid a very large number of unnecessary read operations, so this approach is very important for me to keep

Thanks in advance for the answer

Note: To clarify, this case study I wrote for the sake of learning io.Pipe, nothing more. I simplified my code, but this code doesn't work, and I don't understand why. What is going on that causes the error and yet I can save the result to a file and work with it without any problems

Comment: I agree. I haven't traced through the code in detail to find where you may be hitting a closed pipe, but I would bet that almost all of this is an unnecessary complication, and can be achieved much more simply.

Comment: @JimB, I've already made it simpler, but I want to understand why my code doesn't work. What causes the channel to close, but still, I can save the file and work with it

Comment: I noticed these issues when reading the question again, but the issues are probably not the cause of the problem: (1) Use os.Pipe when communicating with subprocess, not io.Pipe.  (2) The code that copies `fileBytes` to `writer` does not handle read errors correctly.  Simplify and fix by using io.Copy.